# OpenAI remove key access while using AAD authentication

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am calling Azure OpenAI API in my python code. To set it up, we need to provide a few parameters, one of which is `openai.api_key`. There are 2 options to get this value -

1. Static key
2. AAD Token

I am using AAD token (refer this - https://github.com/openai/openai-python#microsoft-azure-active-directory-authentication) but still I can access it using the static key. I want to remove the static key access.

Is there any way to disable the static key and only authenticate using AAD authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable the static key and only authenticate using AAD authentication?

If you need to authenticate using only AAD authentication without using **`api.key`** you can use the below code with **`request`** method using Python.

First, create an application and assign **`Cognitive Services User`** role to your application.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import requests
import json


tenantid="xxxxx"
clientid="xxxxx"
clientsecret="xxxxxx"

auth_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': clientid,
    'client_secret': clientsecret,
    'scope': 'https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default'
}
response = requests.post(auth_url, data=data).json()
access_token=response['access_token']

url="https://YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME/completions?api-version=2023-05-15"

h1 = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
}

body={
    "prompt":"MS Dhoni is greatest captain",
    "max_tokens": 100
}
response = requests.post(url,headers=h1,data=json.dumps(body))
s=json.loads(response.text)
d=json.dumps(s,indent=3)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
  {
   "id": "cmpl-880wqMQxxxxxxxPl",
   "object": "text_completion",
   "created": 1696xxxx0,
   "model": "text-davinci-002",
   "choices": [
      {
         "text": " India has had, he is motivation: Ravichandran AshwinR Ashwin tweeted saying MS Dhoni has given all he had to India cricket for over 15 years and has been a motivation for everybody. Michael holding reveals his best captain story and it involves Kapil and Viv. The Indians were taken by surprise and after the initial shock it took off from there.New Zealand lost by 15 runs. It is a catch that has a contenders for the most iconic cricketing pictures.\n\nIndia",
         "index": 0,
         "finish_reason": "length",
         "logprobs": null
      }
   ],
   "usage": {
      "completion_tokens": 100,
      "prompt_tokens": 6,
      "total_tokens": 106
   }
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to configure Azure OpenAI Service with managed identities - Azure OpenAI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/managed-identity#assign-yourself-to-the-cognitive-services-user-role)